# AngularJS unserialize PHP string

Tags: php, json, angularjs, serialization

I have a PHP project which provides a api endpoint exposing JSON data. Part of that data are serialized strings generated in PHP.

In a nodejs application I can unserialize that data using the [php-unserialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-serialize) package. However, I am a complete beginner at Angular and can't find a similar package for AngularJS.

I would appreciate some direction on **how to unserialize a string into JSON data in AngularJS**
and, **where I can find AngularJS packages?**

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS framework does not have a service that decodes array and objects serialized by [PHP serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

Instead encode using [PHP json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

I seriously recommend that PHP APIs avoid using `serialize` to communicate data.

From Anonymous:<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#107717)</sup>

> Please! please! please! DO NOT serialize data and place it into your database. Serialize can be used that way, but that's missing the point of a relational database and the datatypes inherent in your database engine. Doing this makes data in your database non-portable, difficult to read, and can complicate queries. If you want your application to be **portable to other languages**, like let's say you find that you want to use Java for some portion of your app that it makes sense to use Java in, serialization will become a pain in the buttocks. You should always be able to query and modify data in the database without using a third party intermediary tool to manipulate data to be inserted.
>
> I've encountered this too many times in my career, it makes for **difficult to maintain code**, code with **portability issues**, and data that is it more **difficult to migrate** to other RDMS systems, new schema, etc. It also has the added disadvantage of making it messy to search your database based on one of the fields that you've serialized.
>
> That's not to say `serialize()` is useless. It's not... A good place to use it may be a cache file that contains the result of a data intensive operation, for instance. There are tons of others... Just don't abuse serialize because the next guy who comes along will have a maintenance or migration nightmare.

The [JSON Standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is well supported by most languages and widely used for data interchange on the Web. The AngularJS [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) supports it automatically by default.